# Wilting purple passion clipping

Tags: propagation, wilting

I have a clipping propagating in water. I've done this a few times with no problem. This time it looked great for a week, then yesterday started drooping. The color looks healthy and the leaves are soft, but they droop badly. I'm not sure what could be causing it or what to do.

[image]

Comment: Despite its popularity, rooting in water is not a stunningly reliable method. So, sometimes things don't work out.

While it's cool to be able to see the roots forming in water, something with damp vermiculite/perlite/peat/sand often works better in terms of actually rooting cuttings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update. I brought it a little closer to the light and re-clipped the stem and it almost immediately started rooting. Now it is over a foot long and healthy.